# Log individual users out of a period of inactivity?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, user-account, system-settings

There is a setting under Security & Privacy -> Advanced, to "Log out after X minutes of inactivity".  However, this is a system wide setting.  I just want to have my kids account log out after a period of inactivity, but leave my account logged in.  Is that possible?

Comment: @GrahamMiln I don't think this is a duplicate. It's broader than the question you linked to, so people searching for this will more likely find an answer

Comment: See also [Logging out one specific user after inactivity?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324265/) Linking this to help tie together similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The MacEnterprise list has discussed this topic recently, [Forcing Log-Off For Idle Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/macenterprise/zK9Bl13vps8).

## `autologout` Defaults

John NcNair suggested the following `autologout` defaults:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay -int 900 
defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.securitypref.logoutvalue -int 900
```

#### Limitations

Bruce Carter mentioned...

> Note that nothing using Apple's internal mechanism for this will work if 
>   the user has unsaved files open.  It will simply stop at the dialog box and 
>   time out.

See the related question [How can I automatically log out the guest account after a period of inactivity?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/how-can-i-automatically-log-out-the-guest-account-after-a-period-of-inactivity) for other approaches and tools.